# Nil Instance Variable in Rails Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a problem accessing my instance variable inside my edit view. I am creating an edit form to change the values and update the database. My edit.html.erb is:

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit Campaign") %>
<h1>Update your Campaign</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@campaign, url: edit_campaign_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
        ...
      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The error I receive is that the *First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty*. I have checked in shell and @campaign is nil, though the edit_campaign_path is proper and the id is present.

In the new.html.erb, I am able to use:

```
<%= form_for(@campaign) do |f| %>
```

without any issues. Why is it when I go to edit, the instance variable is nil?

Comment: I suspect Yang's answer is right, but we need the controller code for CampaignsController

Comment: Can you please show your `edit` code from the controller?

Comment: I was missing the @ symbol in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `@campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])` in your `CampaignController#edit`

Comment: Thank you. I added this to my controller and it worked like a charm!